# PHP radio button

Tags: php, jquery

Ok so Im trying to use radio buttons in my PHP code. I wrote a Madlib in PHP and I want to write in a radio button that when a user selects it, it will change the story etc. Happy ending or sad ending here the code I have so far. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>James Nygaard's Mablib</title>
    </head>

    <body bgcolor="<?php echo $bg; ?>" text="<?php echo $fg; ?>">

        <h1 style="font-family:cursive;">Create your Madlib below:</h1>

        <form action="" method="post">

            Enter the name of a boy:
            <input name="noun1" type="text" value="<?= $_POST['noun1'] ?>" /><br />

            Enter an Adjective that describes a person:
            <input name="adj1" type="text" value="<?= $_POST['adj1'] ?>" /><br />

            Enter the name of a man:
            <input name="noun2" type="text" value="<?= $_POST['noun2'] ?>" /><br />

            Enter an Adjective that describes a person:
            <input name="adj2" type="text" value="<?= $_POST['adj2'] ?>" /><br />

            Enter the name of a woman:
            <input name="noun3" type="text" value="<?= $_POST['noun3'] ?>" /><br />

            Enter your favorite animal:
            <input name="noun4" type="text" value="<?= $_POST['noun4'] ?>" /><br />

            Enter a name:
            <input name="noun5" type="text" value="<?= $_POST['noun5'] ?>" /><br />

            Enter the name of your favorite city:
            <input name="noun6" type="text" value="<?= $_POST['noun6'] ?>" /><br />

            Enter a feeling that ends in "ness":
            <input name="adj3" type="text" value="<?= $_POST['adj3'] ?>" /><br />

            Enter a Verb that ends in "ing":
            <input name="verb2" type="text" value="<?= $_POST['verb2'] ?>" /><br />

            Enter the name of a boy:
            <input name="noun7" type="text" value="<?= $_POST['noun7'] ?>" /><br />

            Enter the name of a girl:
            <input name="noun8" type="text" value="<?= $_POST['noun8'] ?>" /><br />

            <input type="submit" value="Click here or press enter to see your MadLib"  /><br />

        </form>

        <div style="color: #2F4F4F; font-family: cursive;">
            <?php
            $bg = "8FBC8F";
            $fg = "2F4F4F";

            if(isset($_POST['noun1'])) {

                echo "<h1> The adventures of {$_POST['noun1']}. </h1>";

                echo "This is where i will put the story. I already have the story but the code is    really long so I left it out of this question.";

                echo "<br> The end.";
            }
            ?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any particular reason you're using php instead of js for this if everything is going to be inline anyway?

Comment: Im trying to learn php and use it on my localhost.

Comment: this isn't how I would go about it. If you want to really learn php, put all your story text in a database and use php to query it and serve to the web - it's more technically complex but will teach you far more about the nuts and bolts. this is just copy pasting

Comment: @JustinNygaard You could get rid of all `value="<?= $_POST['noun1'] ?>"` etc. (input fields) to save you some keystrokes (later on if every the occasion were ever to present itself again) and put a `foreach` in your handler to output all your form fields. 'tis indeed an indispensable tool ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not especially clear in this small space, but I tried to follow your code style.

```
Select an option:
<label>
    <input name="some_option" type="radio" value="option_1" <?php if(isset($_POST['some_option']) && $_POST['some_option'] == 'option_1') echo 'checked="checked" '; ?>/> Option 1
</label>
<label>
    <input name="some_option" type="radio" value="option_2" <?php if(isset($_POST['some_option']) && $_POST['some_option'] == 'option_2') echo 'checked="checked" '; ?>/> Option 2
</label>
```

If you run that code you should see what's going on.